# Difference between best-effort delivery and at least once delivery in Google Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

What is the difference between [best-effort delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering#:%7E:text=Pub/Sub%20delivers%20each%20message%20at%20least%20once%2C%20so%20the%20Pub/Sub%20service%20might%20redeliver%20messages.:%7E:text=topics%20on%20a-,best%2Deffort%20basis,-.%20When%20redelivered%20messages) and [at least once](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering#:%7E:text=Pub/Sub%20delivers%20each%20message%20at%20least%20once%2C%20so%20the%20Pub/Sub%20service%20might%20redeliver%20messages.:%7E:text=delivers%20each%20message-,at%20least%20once,-%2C%20so%20the%20Pub) delivery in Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best-effort delivery" refers to the sending of messages to the dead-letter topic while "at least once delivery" refers to the sending of messages to subscribers. The latter is the primary guarantee offered by Pub/Sub around delivery: messages that are successfully published to a topic will be delivered to a subscriber for each subscription attached to the topic at least once (unless the message exceeds its messages retention duration and expires). A message could be delivered to a subscriber more than once, even if an acknowledgement request for the message returns successfully. Note that [exactly once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) offers some stronger guarantees.

The "best-effort delivery" indicates that there are no strong guarantees around delivering messages to the dead-letter topic. In general, messages are meant to be sent to the dead letter topic once their delivery count exceeds a provided threshold and usually are. However, the delivery count may reset and/or the publish to the dead letter topic could fail, which results in the message continuing to be redelivered to subscribers.

Comment: Does the delivery count you mentioned denote the count of messages that have not been acked?

Comment: No. It is the number of delivery attempts for a specific message. See the documentation on [dead-letter topics](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#dead-letter_topic).

Comment: Under what cases will the reset of the count of delivery of messages happen?

Comment: There isn't an explicit list of user-controlled cases that can be enumerated. It has to do with how the state is tracked in the service. As the documentation says "The tracked number of delivery attempts for a message may also reset to zero, especially for a pull subscription with inactive subscribers."